# Python Word Search Solver Unable To Generate properly

Tags: python

```
import string
def solve_word_search(words, grid):
    rows = len(grid)
    cols = len(grid[0])
    dirs = [(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)]
    
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    
    for word in words:
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                for d in dirs:
                    dr, dc = d
                    if all(0 <= r + i*dr < rows and 0 <= c + i*dc < cols and grid[r + i*dr][c + i*dc] == word[i] for i in range(len(word))):
                        for i in range(len(word)):
                            grid[r + i*dr][c + i*dc] = '-'
                        break
    
    for row in grid:
        for i, char in enumerate(row):
            if char == '-':
                row[i] = '#'
    
    return grid

def main():
    words_file = input("Enter the name of the file containing the words: ")
    grid_file = input("Enter the name of the file containing the grid: ")
    
    with open(words_file, 'r') as f:
        words = f.read().splitlines()
    
    with open(grid_file, 'r') as f:
        grid = [list(row.strip()) for row in f.readlines()]
    
    solved_grid = solve_word_search(words, grid)
    for row in solved_grid:
        print(" ".join(row))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm having difficulty with this part. To inverse the results, currently, the correct words are shown as dash but the random alphabets are shown normally. Instead, only the correct words should be shown and the other alphabets are placed as a dash.

Also, some of the words are not found by the solver. Any tips or tricks will be greatly appreciated.

The image below shows the outcome; as seen in the 2nd row, the word 'yellow' is not solved.
[image: outcome]
[generated grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARrvB.png)[word txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EkNw.png)
I've changed the sample file letters to lower case to be seen better in the grid.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

So currently, you are replacing the characters of the "correct" word with '-' and subsequently replacing that with '#'. As there is no memory of the original character in this method, there isn't really a way to inverse it.

What you can do is define a second nested list with all hashes/pounds and replace it in there. Keep in mind to use list.copy to avoid re-referencing the same list when you want to change something.

```
# not using the term hash in code since hashes are a part of several datatype like
# hash tables so as to avoid confusion
pound_list_inner = ["#"] * 9
pound_list = []
for i in range(9):
    pound_list.append(pound_list_inner.copy())
```

After this, instead of replacing the letters in your original grid, replace the "#" in the created list. Unless the words in the grid must not overlap, then also replace the letters with - or any arbitrary symbol. Remember to change the return statement as well.

```
if all(0 <= r + i*dr < rows and 0 <= c + i*dc < cols and grid[r + i*dr][c + i*dc].upper() == word[i].upper() for i in range(len(word))):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        pound_list[r + i*dr][c + i*dc] = word[i]
    break
```

You might have noticed that I also added .upper() to the check on the grid's character and word[i]'s character. This is usually a good idea if you aren't particular about the capitalization of the characters you are trying to match because it will remove the possibility that the non-match is caused by a character being capitalized/not capitalized when you intended. I can't confirm if this is the cause of your problem detecting "yellow" with the available information though.